# Php, code competion for inline-factory / dynamic method name?

Tags: php, phpdoc

given this snippet:

```
class Test
{
    public function run2()
    {
    }
}

class Factory
{
    public function createTest()
    {
        return new Test();
    }
}

$factory = new Factory();
$m = 'createTest';
$factory->{$m}->run2();
```

Phpstorm will say most of it are unused:

[image]

of course I can extract the calls:

```
$factory = new Factory();
$m = 'createTest';
$x = $factory->{$m}();
/** @var $x Test */
$x->run2();
```

that way at least run2() is shown:

[image]

is there a "magic" phpdoc which Im not aware of? I dont want to extract method calls.

Comment: Static code analysis doesn't work when you use dynamic methods.

Comment: `$factory->{$m}->run2();` isn't valid, you are missing the `()` (unless I'm missing something). When you say that you "don't want to extract the method calls", you mean that you don't want to create temporary variables, right?

Comment: yea, right, I regard them unnecessary. And no, you dont miss anything, its an untested code

Comment: Please [edit] to include code you've actually tested - that is, a [mre]. It will avoid people wasting their time on irrelevant details and hello them understand what you need.